# compile ffmpeg with libx264 for android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, ffmpeg, libx264

What is wrong with the libx264 path please anyone help me?
I have compiled libx264 latest source code. When I compiled the ffmpeg source using below x264 path . It wont allow me to record video.
Note that: I am compiling libraries by linux

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################
# Usage:
# put this script in top of FFmpeg source tree
# ./build_android
# It generates binary for following architectures:
# ARMv6 
# ARMv6+VFP 
# ARMv7+VFPv3-d16 (Tegra2) 
# ARMv7+Neon (Cortex-A8)
# Customizing:
# 1. Feel free to change ./configure parameters for more features
# 2. To adapt other ARM variants
# set $CPU and $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS 
# call build_one
######################################################

HOME=/home
NDK=$HOME/hfi/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
SYSROOT=$PLATFORM
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
TOOLCHAIN=$PREBUILT

function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--enable-nonfree \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libx264 \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -I /usr/local/include +-fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```